# Solving a probability equation.

Tags: probability, combinations

One group of 30 people won a contest and as a reward they got a free vacation to Hawaii. The hotel they will be in has 10 rooms with 3-bed (bed for 3 people).

The question: How many ways can we deploy the students?

I used combinations because the students can change each other places, so I got:

$$
10 \cdot C_{30}^3,
$$
where   $C_{30}^3 = \binom{30}{3}$.

Is it correct?

Comment: Welcome at SE. It can only be checked if you let us know what the question is.

Comment: Sorry I missed that.. updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you’re trying to count the different ways in which the $30$ students can be distributed amongst the $10$ rooms, it’s not correct. There are $\binom{30}3$ ways to choose the $3$ students who are to occupy the first room. Once they’ve been chosen, only $27$ students remain, so there are $\binom{27}3$ ways to choose $3$ of them for the second room. Continuing in this fashion, we see that there are

$$\begin{align*}
\binom{30}3\binom{27}3\dots\binom33&=\frac{30!}{3!\,27!}\cdot\frac{27!}{3!\,24!}\cdot\ldots\cdot\frac{3!}{3!\,0!}\\
&=\frac{30!}{\underbrace{3!\cdot3!\cdot\ldots\cdot3!}_{10}}\\
&=\frac{30!}{3!^{10}}\\\\
&=\binom{30}{3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3}\;,
\end{align*}$$

a [multinomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem).

Comment: So in this case, it's not permutation/variation or combination? We have learned "multinominal coefficient" yet, nor we had this kind of solution ever before.

Comment: @user108030: No, it’s not a simple permutation or combination problem. (I suspected that you might not have seen multinomial coefficients, which is why I gave the answer in several forms.) The basic analysis, though, is just the usual counting of choices at each stage of a multichoice problem and multiplying the results.

Comment: I do understand your logic and everything. But it's kinda odd to me because the solution is so big and can't be calculated with a calculator, because when we had similar exercise before, the solution was very simlier without big numbers. However it really makes sense to me, except I can't get any result as number.

Comment: @user108030: Yes, it’s a pretty big number; the calculator that I’m using says that it’s about $4.3868\times10^{24}$.